# Blazor parent-child example button missing?

Tags: blazor

i made a new blazor app with

```
dotnet new blazor
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0

then i added the parent and child razor components from this tutorial

Parent.razor

```
@page "/ParentComponent"

<h1>Parent-child example</h1>

<ChildComponent Title="Panel Title from Parent"
                OnClick="@ShowMessage">
    Content of the child component is supplied
    by the parent component.
</ChildComponent>

<p><b>@messageText</b></p>

@functions {
    private string messageText;

    private void ShowMessage(UIMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        messageText = "Blaze a new trail with Blazor!";
    }
}
```

Child.razor

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">@Title</div>
    <div class="panel-body">@ChildContent</div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@OnClick">
        Trigger a Parent component method
    </button>
</div>

@functions {
    [Parameter]
    private string Title { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    private RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    private EventCallback<UIMouseEventArgs> OnClick { get; set; }
}
```

it kinda works in that it shows the child and the text content passed from parent to child and the title... but there is no button and therefore no message and no updating of message text

Answer (score 1):

Are your components (.razor) sit in a folder named Pages ?
Try to close Visual Studio, and then run your app again. 
This is very strange...

Comment: they are in pages folder... i am using vscode... will try to rename page ParentComponent.razor instead of Parent.razor like the route

Answer (score 0):

The page file name must match the route defined with @Page?

Though it shows with no error message even if not same?

Renaming my Parent.razor & Child.razor to ParentComponent.razor and ChildComponent.razor fixes it. Excuse my ignorance. Thanks.

edit: oh ya i guess file name must match "ChildComponent" from the razor code

Comment: No, the `@Page` can be anything. But the filename becomes the class name becomes the Component name.